# React Native FlatList extending beyond screen when rendered with a header

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a header that renders above a `FlatList` component. If the screen is 800px tall, the header is 100px tall, the `FlatList` should fill up 700px (with `flexGrow: 1`), and be scrollable (if there are too many `ListItems`). Basic markup is as follows:

```
<View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'soothing-yellow-thunder'}}>
  <Header style={{height: 100}} />

  <FlatList ... />
</View>
```

However, when I render the header, the height of the `FlatList` component is actually 800px, matching the height of the wrapping component with `flexGrow: 1`. I can tell it's 800px - the last 100px of which is accessible only by intentionally scrolling past where the FlatList believes the end is. The `FlatList` "extra" height is ***exactly*** as far as the header is tall. Actual working code, and a link to a snack (which should allow you to reproduce in browser, or on your phone if you have expo installed):

https://snack.expo.io/@sgardn04/flatlist-header-example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  _renderList() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={[{key: '0', content: 'hello there 0'}, {key: '1', content: 'hello there 1'}, {key: '2', content: 'hello there 2'}, {key: '3', content: 'hello there 3'}, {key: '4', content: 'hello there 4'},]}
        renderItem={({item}) => { return <View style={{height: 140, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1}}><Text>{item.content}</Text></View> }} />
    )
  }

  _renderListWithHeader() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexGrow: 1}}>
        <View style={{height: 70, backgroundColor: 'lime', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}><Text>Header</Text></View>

        {this._renderList()}
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this._renderListWithHeader()
      // this._renderList()
    )
  }
}
```

What am I misunderstanding about how flex layouts work? I was under the impression that the `FlatList` component was effectively wrapped by something that has `flexGrow: 1`, so the container will grow to fill available space but not overflow. Obviously the list could have ten times as much vertical content as space allows for, but the fact that it's exactly off by the height of the header is very suspicious. What's actually going on here? If you'd like to see what I consider "working" behavior, try switching the commented methods in the render method of the code I have posted (and adding items to the data if you have a larger screen so it overflows).

Answer (score 10):

Simply just give `flex:1` to style of your parent `View`.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<View></View>
<Flatlist/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

The FlatList actually accepts a prop for styling a header, this will work much better than trying to create your own: [FlatList Header](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent)

As far as flex goes, you should pass the `flex`, or `flexGrow`, prop down to the `<View>` component that is actually wrapping the FlatList.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the `FlatList` header property, because in the real code the list actually renders based on a few cases. When the data is loading, there's a loading spinner, so in that case I can't render the list component just for the header. I actually want to always render the header for the screen and then to render one of a few possibilities for content to the page.

Comment: @gards can't you still use the header prop, then use the ListEmpytComponent prop to display the spinner - or content when it's ready?

Comment: That feels a bit like abusing the `ListEmptyComponent` prop into being used as for "List empty or loading". I think it would work, but I also honestly want to know what `FlatList` here is doing something unexpected (or why what I expect is wrong).

Comment: That's exactly what that method is for though. So you can render something when there is no data. We use this in our production apps all the time.